# Python:ValueError: scatter requires y column to be numeric?

Tags: python, pandas

**Using pd.Dataframe won't convert columns of lists into dataframe :**

Below are my lines of code for reading in a `.mat file` and converting it into a `dataframe` from the many examples that I have seen.

However, when I read the data in the columns they still remain as `lists` with square brackets around the data. What I am trying to do is **convert this into a proper dataframe** so I can plot the last column (time data) along with the other columns as an **`x`** and **`y`** scatter plot. But the error I get is **ValueError: scatter requires y column to be numeric**. I have not shown the code for plotting the **`x`** and **`y`**  data.

```
import mat4py as mp
data = mp.loadmat('test.mat')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

When I type:

```
df.columns
```

I get the following:

```
Index(['col 1', 'col 2',
       'col 3', 'col 4', ... 'col 189'] with dtype='object', length=189)
```

If I type:

```
df.['col 1']
```

I get the following:

```
Out[95]: 
0       [0.0]
1       [0.0]
2       [0.0]
3       [0.0]
4       [0.0]
5       [0.0]
6       [0.0]
7       [0.0]
8       [0.0]
9       [0.0] 
... 1622 rows in total.
```

I even tried using .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') to the columns and that does not work either. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:
The solution in the comments presented below applied only for a single column, but I wanted this to apply to every cell in the dataframe. When using .apply(lambda ..) on a whole dataframe, the columns become the index and messes up the dataframe. I found the solution that would properly apply the lambda to each cell and retain the dataframe. It is as follows:

```
mm = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

Many thanks to those who provided the original lambda solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col 1':[[0.0],[0.0]]})
df
Out[49]: 
   col 1
0  [0.0]
1  [0.0]
df['col 1'].apply(lambda x : x[0])
Out[50]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
Name: col 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @RafaelC yep , it may happen , we may need convert the using ast

Comment: nice +1 for list solution :)

Comment: I just tried the lambda and it does indeed work. How would I apply this to each and every column in the dataframe?

Comment: @GusG assign it back ? df=df.apply(lambda x : x[0])

Comment: Wen, yes I forgot to assign it back. In case you missed my edited comment, how do apply this to all the columns in the dataframe in one pass?

Comment: @GusG `df=df.apply(lambda x : x[0],1)`

Answer (score 2):

If `[0.0]` are strings,

```
import ast
df.c.transform(ast.literal_eval).str[0]
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8    0.0
9    0.0
```

Comment: Wen/Rafaeil, the data is from Matlab so what I will be plotting are float values using plot scatter. How can I apply this transform to all 189 columns?And how do I convert what you just did to float values?